# Selenium Java best practices for handling different languages and locations, and setting dynamic architecture

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Im currently working on a platform that has multi-language options and also the language is defined by IP. So Im trying to build an architecture for testing both scenarios dynamically... The domain is always the same: Example: [www.page.com](http://www.page.com) (If you are logged in from Britain the web application is loaded in English, if you are visiting the page from France the page is loaded in French.)

I have an idea to make different abstract classes with error messages for example:

```java
public class ErrorMessagesEN {

   public static final String MANDATORY_FIELD = "This field is mandatory...";
   public static final String SOME_OTHER_ERROR_MSG = "Some error message on english"

// etc.....

}

public class ErrorMessagesFR {

    public static final String MANDATORY_FIELD = "Error message in French"
    public static final String SOME_OTHER_ERROR_MSG = "Some error message on 
French"

// etc.....
}
```

In the test method i provide parameter "EN" or "FR" for example:

```java
homepage.signIn(String location)
```

So is there any option to make for example:

```java
if (location=="EN") {
   // load the ErrorMessageEN
   // etc......
}
```

The keys for the Strings are the same but the classes are different, so how can I provide different imports of the classes by the location parameter for example? Or are there any better approaches for this situation? Any links or ideas?

Thanks!

PS. If you need more info to help me please ask! :)

Comment: I have a [small lib on github](https://github.com/webelement-click/parameterized-findby)  that might help you with your issue. There is also some more explanation [here](https://webelement.click/en/parameterized_findby_annotation_in_selenium_page_object_java).

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid this conditional (if locations == "EN"), using dependency injection, on the code that is concerned with the application test itself.

You can:

- Create a module to deal with the data;
- Create an Interface to abstract the capabilities of this module (e.g. called Messages);
- Have class for each language you want:

  public class final ErrorMessagesFR implements Messages

  public class final ErrorMessagesEN implements Messages
- Choose the concrete object to be injected based on, for instance, command line arguments or environmental variables.

Then on the application test code, you can use like this:

```
public class HomePage {
   ...
   public HomePage(Message messages){ this.messages = messages; }

   ...

   public void signIn() { ... message.MANDATORY_FIELD...  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using separate classes for error messages based on the location is a good one. To dynamically load the appropriate error messages class, you could use the following approach:

1. Create a base class for error messages that defines the error message keys as static final fields, as you have done.
2. Create subclasses for each language that extend the base error message class and provide the translations for the error message keys in that language.
3. Create a utility class with a method that takes the location as a parameter and returns an instance of the appropriate error message class.
4. In your test method, call the utility class method to get the error message class for the current location, and use the error messages from that class in your test assertions.

Here's example code for this approach:

```
public abstract class BaseErrorMessages {
    public static final String MANDATORY_FIELD = "This field is mandatory...";
    public static final String SOME_OTHER_ERROR_MSG = "Some error message";
    // etc...
}

public class ErrorMessagesEN extends BaseErrorMessages {
    public static final String MANDATORY_FIELD = "This field is mandatory in English...";
    // etc...
}

public class ErrorMessagesFR extends BaseErrorMessages {
    public static final String MANDATORY_FIELD = "This field is mandatory in French...";
    // etc...
}

public class ErrorMessageUtils {
    public static BaseErrorMessages getErrorMessages(String location) {
        if (location.equals("EN")) {
            return new ErrorMessagesEN();
        } else if (location.equals("FR")) {
            return new ErrorMessagesFR();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported location: " + location);
        }
    }
}

public class MyTest {
    public void test(String location) {
        BaseErrorMessages errorMessages = ErrorMessageUtils.getErrorMessages(location);
        String mandatoryFieldErrorMessage = errorMessages.MANDATORY_FIELD;
        // use the error messages in your test assertions...
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to load the appropriate error message class dynamically based on the location parameter passed to the `getErrorMessages` method.